# Thread won't enter synchronized block

Tags: java, android, multithreading, synchronized

I have a Button in my android app which must run a continuous action while holding it down, for that I created an `onTouchListener` to handle such issue, my structure is when catching `ACTION_DOWN` event a thread with a while(true) loop runs, then when catching `ACTION_UP` event that thread stopped via `wait()` in order to resume it's looping again upon holding down, the problem is that when trying to execute `thread.wait()` the thread doesn't enter the synchronized block and doesn't wait, but it stops the execution of `runOnUIThread` which exists in that thread, and after I press any button after that the app crashes and gives me `ANR Exception : Input dispatching timed out`:

```
   // the thread declaratrion
    test = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            while (true) {
                // still loops here
                value = value + 1;
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        // doesn't go here anymore
                        mTextView.setText(Integer.toString(value));
                    }
                });
                // still loops here
                synchronized (test) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(150);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    });

    // the onTouchListener
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        if (!test.isAlive()) {
            synchronized (test) {
                test.start();
            }
        } else {
            synchronized (test) {
                test.notify();
            }
        }
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        // accepts the action
        synchronized (test) {
            try {
                // doesn't goes here
                test.wait(); // doesn't execute
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
```

Comment: a ghost downvoter that downvotes and leave without any helping action, that's what I was missing here :D

Answer (score 0):

Probably you use too low level API for your needs. Just look at http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html

Comment: I think instead of strugling with low level API I'd better use one that fits better

Answer (score 0):

One thing I see is potential dangerous is that in your separate thread, you are waiting inside a synchronized statement. So when that guy is sleeping, it takes the lock with him, and therefore in your onTouchListener, none could grabbed the lock but to wait. And because the onTouchListener is controlled in the framework, it may stop running if it waits too long. I did a simple test [here](http://ideone.com/WIsSOi) to prove it.

```
class Ideone
{
        public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        final Object globalLock = new Object();
        Thread t1  = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                synchronized (globalLock) {
                    System.out.println("thread1 grabbed the lock.");
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(3000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    System.out.println("thread1 returned the lock.");
                }
            }
        });
        t1.start();

        Thread.sleep(200);

        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("thread2 is waiting for the lock...");
                synchronized (globalLock) {
                    System.out.println("thread2 got the lock");
                }
            }
        });
        t2.start();
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
    }
}
```

Comment: well, I tried such way but didn't solve the problem.